# Cardinality of $ X\times \mathbb{N} $ when $X$ is infinite

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Suppose $X$ is infinite. I think we can show that $|X\times\mathbb{N}| = |X|$. How do we construct an injective function $f:X\times\mathbb{N} \to X$?

Comment: The axiom of choice is necessary here, so you cannot construct an injection like that. However using choice, or one of its many equivalents, we can do it quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

When $X$ is infinite you can partition as $X=\sqcup_{i\in I}X_i$, each $X_i$ being in one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$. Let us call $\phi_i : X_i\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such a bijection. Then, the "trick" is to construct a bijection between $X_i\times \mathbb{N}$ and $X_i$ which can be done through any bijection between $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How is such a partition constructed?

Comment: @Alexis: You cannot construct such a partition, since the axiom of choice is necessary here.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Well, starting from such an unframed question, I admit I assumed that we were within ZFC (standard default assumption). Now, you need a form of axiom of choice in order to get the partition, afterwards the remaining part is constructible.